# Which API should I use to get Github feed?

Tags: api, github

I'm currently working on Github API. I'd like to get news feed like we can see at https://github.com . I'd like to get information same as the authenticated user can see on the top page of github.com. I'm browsing Github's api documentation here: https://developer.github.com/v3/ . But I can't tell which is the right for my purpose. Anyone give a help to detect which is the best API for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found which API is right for me by checking response from each API. 
`GET /users/:username/received_events` is the one that I was looking for.

https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-events-that-a-user-has-received